# Recommended Python Atom feed generator?

Tags: python, rss, atom-feed

Which Python library is commonly used today to generate Atom feeds?

Note, there exists a very [similar question from 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117/recommended-python-rss-atom-feed-generator), but its answers are mostly obsolete. The library *atomxlib* was recommended, but it apparently is obsolete (also the website does not exist anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [webhelpers.feedgenerator](http://webhelpers.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/feedgenerator.html). It supports Atom1 feeds.

Answer (score 5):

For future Googlers, the recommended library ([WebHelpers](https://webhelpers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) doesn't support Python 3, and it appears to be abandoned. There was a rewrite, [WebHelpers2](https://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it doesn't include the feed generator, and it seems to be end-of-lifed. "Version 2.0 is the final release."

[feedgen](https://pypi.org/project/feedgen/) looks more up to date, it can generate both Atom and RSS feeds, and it supports Python 3 (as well as Python 2).

Answer (score 5):

It's a surprisingly non trivial question.

Looking into what known projects are using, that generates rss, my two main options are:

- [python-feedgen](https://github.com/lkiesow/python-feedgen) is popular and [documented](https://feedgen.kiesow.be/), but (in 2021-05-01) [don't have activity](https://github.com/lkiesow/python-feedgen/issues/106) since the beginning of 2020.
- [feedgenerator](https://github.com/getpelican/feedgenerator) with recent activity and used by 2.7k projects, but with minimal [documentation](https://github.com/getpelican/feedgenerator/blob/master/tests_feedgenerator/usage_example.py)  (or you have to extrapolate from [django rss docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/syndication/))
- [rfeed](https://github.com/svpino/rfeed), but have a [strange](https://github.com/svpino/rfeed/issues/9) PyPI publication method and (in 2021-05-01) don't have activity since the beginning of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

How about [rfeed](https://github.com/svpino/rfeed)?

Another one I found is the AtomFeed from Werkzeug ([Atom Syndication](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/contrib/atom/)), but the functionality is removed since the version 1.0. So I found a fork at [feedwerk](https://pypi.org/project/feedwerk/).

Answer (score -1):

I would use one of the many templating systems out there (like Jinja2, Mako, ...)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could reuse Django's [syndication feed framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/#django.contrib.syndication.django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed). Altough you should notice that it's usually best practice to write it by yourself because generating XML is rather simple and there's few value in using a generator as is, as mentioned by lazy1.